# Duda: ¿Cómo prosegir con un bucle while después de salir de él con un except?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles, excepciones

el caso es que llevo un par de días con python, por lo que soy bastante inválido, y quería hacer un programa que te pidiese 10 números, sumara los pares y los impares y los mostrase en pantalla al final.

El caso es que para que no de error al introducir un str que no sea un número he hecho un except; ahí es donde llega mi duda, cómo puedo hacer para que el except no me corte el while como me lo corta actualmente.

He mirado en todos lados, pero no he encontrado nada, a ver si me pueden ayudar con esto, que fijo que es algo bastante simple.

Les adjunto código:

```
i = 0
list = []
suma_pares = 0
suma_impares = 0

try:

    while i < 10:
        i += 1
        number = input('Inserte número: ')
        number = int(number)
        list.append(number)

except ValueError:
    print("Solo se pueden introducir números")
    
for number in list:
    if number == 0:
        suma_pares = suma_pares
    elif (number % 2) == 0:
        suma_pares += number
    else:
        suma_impares += number

print(f"La suma de los números pares es: {suma_pares}.")
print(f"La suma de los números impares es: {suma_impares}.")
```

Gracias de antemano, y perdonen si la duda es de inválido, pero me tiene bastante bloqueado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al ejecutar tu codigo te va a decir que la `i` no está definida, por lo que lo primero sería definirla.

Lo siguiente sería poner el try dentro del `while`, al intentar transformarlo a `integer`, así si no puede te salta la excepción.

Por último, para que ese ciclo no cuente (si se ha metido una letra) el `i += 1` debería ir dentro del `try`, así solo sumará 1 si es un número.

```
i=0
while i < 10:
    number = input('Inserte número: ')
    try:
        number = int(number)
        i += 1
    except ValueError:
        print("Solo se pueden introducir números")
    list.append(number)
```

Puedes también mejorar el código, si a medida que vas recibiendo los números, los vas sumando ya, así no tienes que volver a iterar por ellos. Puedes ir almacenandolo por ejemplo en un diccionario:

```
d={'par':0,'impar':0}  #Crea un diccionario para pares e impares

i=0
while i < 10:
    number = input('Inserte número: ')
    try:
        n = int(number)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            d['par'] += n  #Si n es par lo añade aquí.
        else:
            d['impar'] += n  #Si n es impar lo añade aquí.
        i += 1
    except ValueError:
        print("Solo se pueden introducir números")

print(f"La suma de los números pares es: {d['par']}.")
print(f"La suma de los números impares es: {d['impar']}.")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con lo de que la i no está definida te refieres a que no está definida dentro del try, ¿no?

Comment: Igual que defines `suma_pares` y `suma_impares` y les asignas valor 0, con la `i` tienes que hacer lo mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Una solucion rápida a tu problema es introducir el except dentro del ciclo while:

```
list = []
suma_pares = 0
suma_impares = 0
i = 0
while i < 10:
   number = input('Inserte número: ')
   try:
      number = int(number)
   except ValueError:
      print("Solo se pueden introducir números")
      continue
   list.append(number)
   i += 1
    
for number in list:
    if number == 0:
        suma_pares = suma_pares
    elif (number % 2) == 0:
        suma_pares += number
    else:
        suma_impares += number

print(f"La suma de los números pares es: {suma_pares}.")
print(f"La suma de los números impares es: {suma_impares}.")
```

Para futuras referencia, recordá que try y except en la medida de lo posible, solo deben contener el código que genera la excepción, en tu caso, int (number)

Una solución mas elegante, y que no genera código excepcional, es usar comprobaciones de digitos:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
   number = input('Inserte número: ')
   if number.strip().isdigit(): # asumiendo que los numeros seran no negativos
      number = int(number)
   else:
      print("Solo se pueden introducir números")
      continue
   list.append(number)
   i += 1
```

Comment: Recomiendo que en lugar de usar `.isdigit`, uses `.isnumeric`, ya que el primero toma como valido caracteres como "²". Mas info aqui https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isdigit.asp

Comment: Tienen razón, editaré la respuesta.

Comment: Me di cuenta de que isnumeric no acepta valores negativos, espero que sirva igual. isdigit tampoco acepta negativos, lo comprobé.

Comment: No sabía por ejemplo que .isdigit o .isnumeric existía, el caso es que les he estado dando vueltas a ambos y me parecen los dos lo mismo, no sabría diferenciarlo bien, salvo porque el is.numeric() se traga los ¾ a diferencia del is.digit(), aunque son bastante útiles los dos procedimientos. Además he aprendido también el continue statement, me ha parecido súper útil, gracias por ayudarme :)

Comment: "Para futuras referencia, recordá que try y except en la medida de lo posible, solo deben contener el código que genera la excepción, en tu caso, int (number)"  Esto no lo entendí bien, supongo que usará memoria extra y no será lo optimo, te refieres a eso, no? Sinceramente, soy "nuevo", controlo muy poco xd

Comment: Gracias @DanteS.

Comment: @Chad-Programmer En todos los lenguajes de programación, hay funciones que "lanzaran" excepciones cuando no haya forma de que internamente estas se puedan controlar, en pocas palabras lo dejan al criterio del usuario de la función el controlar dica excepción, es preferible hacer "saneamiento de los datos" en lugar de depender del "lanzamiento de excepciones". Algunas excepciones tienen alta prioridad de ejecución, el sistema operativo las atiendo con mas prioridad, entonces estas haciendo que un programa demande mas atención de la que merece. Sanear tus datos es lo que te propuse de segundo.

Comment: Tienes razón, entonces te refieres a que el except gasta más recursos y que podría plantear este problema con una alternativa que gaste menos, no?

Comment: @Chad-Programmer tenes que estar claro que depende que llames mas recursos, claramente tu programa es una nimiedad para un SO, y procesadores actuales. Sin embargo lo dejo a tu criterio investigar cuanto implica una intrucción try except a una instruccion if else, asi sabras que el saneamiento de datos tienen sus recompensas. Desde luego, no simpre podrás NO usar un try except, pero en la medida que estudies y practiques, tomaras esa decisión de forma mas profesional, en lugar de solo copiar y pegar código.

Comment: Tiene sentido, gracias :)

Comment: @DanteS. me acabo de dar cuenta que .isdecimal() es mejor, ya que solo coge caracteres del (0-9), sin contar ¾ ni ²

Comment: @Chad-Programmer creo que me confundí, quise decir ese mismo xD

Comment: @DanteS.ah vale, ya decía yo xD, gracias aun así :D